# SVN Commit failed for folder/directory

Tags: xcode, svn, directory, commit

SVN is failing to commit [add]ed folder. I added a new folder/directory "ImagesSubDirectory" and placed a couple of images in it. Xcode is showing "A" for all the added images. "svn status" terminal command shows "A" for both the ImagesSubDirectory and the images in this directory. However, when i try to commit this to the server i get the follower error:

> svn: Commit failed (details follow): svn:
>   '/Path/Project/ProjectDirectory/Resources/Images/ImagesSubDirectory'
>   is not under version control and is not part of the commit, yet its
>   child
>   '/Path/Project/ProjectDirectory/Resources/Images/ImagesSubDirectory/MyImage@2x.png'
>   is part of the commit

The Xcode commit dialog is not showing "A" against the "ImagesSubDirectory". What's wrong, and how do I fix it? I can use Terminal, but Xcode should handle it, right?

p.s. I'm using Xcode Version 4.3.2 (4E2002)

Comment: did you try adding the new files to version control first? Select SVN-Add from the context menu.

Comment: They are added. The status of all the files is "A" both in Xcode and in Terminal (when i run svn status).

Comment: have you tried svn add command on folder itself?

Comment: seems like a problem with the parent directory. Try svn add /ImagesSubDirectory on the terminal.

Comment: svn add command on the folder results in a message that says that it's already added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just buggy Xcode + SVN behavior.

I had to use Terminal to fix the issue(s) in the end.

Comment: Maybe add the solution too?

Answer (score 2):

add a "@" character at the end of **all** "`@2x`" files while checking in and your problem with subversion will be solved.

in other words, "`svn add blahblah@2x.png@`" (where blahblah is the true name of the Retina high rez image files) at the terminal and then explicitly commit that.  In other words, don't add these files from Xcode, use the command line in the Terminal.

Subversion can have troubles with files with "@" in the filename.

Answer (score 1):

here is my case's solution:
in Terminal, using svn to first add file then commit:

1.file is xxx@3x.png: `image_file_name@3x.png`

2.then add xxx\@3x.png into svn:

```
svn add image_file_name\@3x.png@
```

3.fiannaly to commit:

```
svn commit -m “add your comment here"
```